# ipojo custom handlers - auto attached handlers - issue in attaching to specific components

Tags: components, handlers, interceptor

I have an issues concerning the custom auto handlers in ipojo. I have created an handler (say Handler-Auto), I want this handler to be auto attached to a POJO component instances (say Comp-1) without touching the metadata of POJO components.
To achieve this, we need to set the "org.apache.felix.ipojo.handler.auto.primitive" variable in the system property with the list of handlers as specified in the below link:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-2594?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel#issue-tabs

The problem  is, when I do like this, my handler (Handler-Auto) is attached to all the components or instances that are created or deployed over the system. To intercept methods or fields from a  particular component we need to add filter at the handler.  But its too late to add filter after attaching handlers with all unnecessary stuffs.

Instead of attaching the handler to all the components,   Is there anyway that, this handler (Handler-Auto) can me made to be attached to a specific components or instances ? as per the user wish.

It would be great if we have this feature and it ll become very dynamic.

Please help if there is any other way to do this or what could be the solution to achieve this ??

thanks for your help in advance!

Thanks,
Sadish